# Microsoft Rest ServiceClientTracing - how to output tracing results to Console or Debug?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

`ServiceClientTracing` class has `static boolean IsEnabled` property that allows you to turn tracing on. But when you set property to `true` no output is showing in Console/Debug or anywhere else.

How to set tracing so that output is visible in either Console/Debug Window (or anywhere really)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Seems that this is not supported by default in `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` project, so you need to role your own class. For example:

```
class DebugTracer : IServiceClientTracingInterceptor
{
    public void Information(string message)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public void TraceError(string invocationId, Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception in {0}: {1}", invocationId, exception);
    }

    public void ReceiveResponse(string invocationId, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        string requestAsString = (response == null ? string.Empty : response.AsFormattedString());
        Debug.WriteLine("invocationId: {0}\r\nresponse: {1}", invocationId, requestAsString);
    }

    public void SendRequest(string invocationId, HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        string requestAsString = (request == null ? string.Empty : request.AsFormattedString());
        Debug.WriteLine("invocationId: {0}\r\nrequest: {1}", invocationId, requestAsString);
    }

    public void Configuration(string source, string name, string value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Configuration: source={0}, name={1}, value={2}", source, name, value);
    }

    public void EnterMethod(string invocationId, object instance, string method, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("invocationId: {0}\r\ninstance: {1}\r\nmethod: {2}\r\nparameters: {3}",
            invocationId, instance, method, parameters.AsFormattedString());
    }

    public void ExitMethod(string invocationId, object returnValue)
    {
        string returnValueAsString = (returnValue == null ? string.Empty : returnValue.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("Exit with invocation id {0}, the return value is {1}",
            invocationId, returnValueAsString);
    }
}
```

[Appropriated from Log4NetTracingInterceptor](https://github.com/stankovski/AutoRest/blob/master/ClientRuntimes/CSharp/Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Log4Net/Log4NetTracingInterceptor.cs).

Now if you want to turn Tracing on all you need to do is:

```
ServiceClientTracing.IsEnabled = true;
ServiceClientTracing.AddTracingInterceptor(new DebugTracer());
```

Comment: This. Is beautiful.

Comment: I am new to this but where it logs ? where to configure file path and log level ? in web.config how? Appreciate if you can give small sample.